# How to clone a canvas in fabric.js to achieve a magnifying glass

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to implement a Magnifying glass in Fabric.js.
I had implemented something [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ankur02/Lakkrkfv/1/) which works fine when using images directly but I have a canvas unfortunately , so I have to first call `canvas.toDataURL()` to create a image followed by cloning it using : `fabric.util.object.clone(img)` which kills a lot of memory .

Can we directly clone a canvas ,something like : `fabric.util.object.clone(canvas);`

Here's a sample code:

```js
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function(img) {
  lens = fabric.util.object.clone(img);
  lens.set({
    width: scale * originalWidth,
    height: scale * originalHeight,
    clipTo: function(ctx) {
      ctx.arc(-this.left + x - this.width / 2, -this.top + y - this.height / 2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    }
  });
  canvas.add(lens);
});
```

Comment: Unless you're willing to be destructive with your un-magnified canvas, a second canvas is the only way.

Comment: but I need to clone another canvas instead of a image. Can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can clone a FabricJS canvas like this:

- Clone the canvas element that you fed into FabricJS.
- Use `drawImage` to draw the FabricJS canvas content onto the cloned canvas

Example:

```
// get a reference to the canvas element you gave to FabricJS
var c=document.getElementById('c');
// clone that canvas with "cloneNode"
var clonedCanvas=c.cloneNode();
// draw the contents of the Fabric canvas onto the cloned canvas
clonedCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(c);
```

But you can create a fabric.Image using a canvas as an image source, so I think you can create an image directly from the Fabric canvas itself.

Untested:

```
var img=fabric.Image(document.getElementById('c'));
```